# Add one DataGridTextColumn to multiple datagrids

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have three datagrids build on three different ObservableCollections of the same type:

```
ObservableCollection<MachineOrder> preactive;
ObservableCollection<MachineOrder> active;
ObservableCollection<MachineOrder> inProduction;
```

MachineOrder contains dictionary of characteristics which i want to add programatically to the grid.

I did it this way:

```
foreach (StringWrapper characteristic in viewModel.Characteristics)
            {

                DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
                column.Header = characteristic.Value;
                column.Width = new DataGridLength(0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);

                Binding binding = new Binding();
                binding.FallbackValue = "kein Wert";
                binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Charakteristics[" + characteristic.Value + "]");

                column.Binding = binding;


                if (dgPreactive.Columns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Header == column.Header) == null)
                    dgPreactive.Columns.Add(column);

                if (dgActive.Columns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Header == column.Header) == null)
                    dgActive.Columns.Add(column);

                if (dgInProduction.Columns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Header == column.Header) == null)
                    dgInProduction.Columns.Add(column);


                if (viewModel.AddedColumns == null)
                        viewModel.AddedColumns = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>();

                if (viewModel.AddedColumns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Header == column.Header) == null)
                    viewModel.AddedColumns.Add(column);

            }
```

`viewModel.Characteristics` contains the Dictionaryitems that i want to display.

This works great the first grid, but on `dgActive.Columns.Add(column)` i get the following argument exception:

"DataGridColumn with Header {0} already exists in the Columns collection of a DataGrid. DataGrids cannot share columns and cannot contain duplicate column instances."

Comment: I am still looking at it but just a code tip. You might want to swamp `if (y.FirstOrDefault(x => ... == ...) == null) ` with `y.All(x => ... != ...)`

Comment: I think you are being very careful not duplicate the column header in any collection but you are sharing the column between the DataGrids.